# pg_dump.exe could not run in IIS8.0

Tags: c#, iis-8, postgresql-9.5, pg-dump, pg-restore

I use System.Diagnostics.Process in C# to call the PostgreSQL backup database component pg_dump.exe. Here is my code:

```
  string argbackup = @"--host localhost --port 5432 --username ""postgres"" --no-password  --format custom --blobs --verbose --file dtname dtname";
  Process backupProcess = new Process();
  backupProcess.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.5/bin/pg_dump.exe";
  backupProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = argbackup;
  backupProcess.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
  backupProcess.Exited += (object sender, EventArgs args) =>    
  {
       //Execution after the process ends.
  };
  backupProcess.Start();
```

The code can run successfully in C#. But pg_dum.exe cannot be called when I publish the project in Visual Studio and deploy it on IIS. And the code that was run after the process ended successfully ran.

I modified the above code:

```
 var pinfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
 pinfo.Arguments = @"--host localhost --port 5432 --username ""postgres"" --no-password  --format custom --blobs --verbose --file dtname dtname";
 info.FileName = @"C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.5/bin/pg_dump.exe";
 pinfo.UseShellExecute = false;
 using (var process = new Process())
 {
       process.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
       process.StartInfo = pinfo;
       process.Start();
       while (!process.HasExited)
           Thread.Sleep(10000);
       process.WaitForExit();
       if (process.ExitCode != 0)
           throw new Exception("error");
       process.Close();
 }
```

It can also be used in C#, but it still won't work in IIS.

I modified the code again:

```
    string argpostgre = @"c: && cd C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.5/bin";
    string argbackup = @"pg_dump.exe --host localhost --port 5432 --username ""postgres"" --no-password  --format custom --blobs --verbose --file dtname dtname";
    Process theProcess = new Process();
    theProcess.StartInfo.FileName = @"cmd.exe"; 
    theProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    theProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
    theProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    theProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true; 
    theProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false; 
    theProcess.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    theProcess.Exited += (object sender, EventArgs args) =>
    {
         //Execution after the process ends.
    };
    string strOutput = null;
    try
    {
        theProcess.Start();
        theProcess.StandardInput.WriteLine(argpostgre + " && " + argbackup + " & exit");
        theProcess.WaitForExit();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        strOutput = ex.Message;
    }
```

It has been runnning in C# and will not exit. But the database can be backed up successfully after I forcefully close the C# program. And it will automatically stop process but the situation is the same as above when I deploy to IIS.

I am sure it is not the setup issue in IIS, because I have also used the Process component to access the WinRAR.exe (C:\Program Files\WinRAR\WinRAR.exe) compression program, which can run successfully.

I wonder if PostgreSQL has permissions so I can not access pg_dump.exe and other components such as pg_restore.exe.

Comment: There are three obvious differences when running processes from an IIS app pool, as opposed to a console app: the app pool identity, the fact that it's not running in an interactive session, and the fact that by default, IIS doesn't load the user profile of an account (so environment variables are possibly missing). Any of these can cause processes to behave differently. The first is easily diagnosed by (temporarily!) making the app run under your own account and the latter by changing the app pool settings. Checking for trouble with non-interactive sessions is harder.

Comment: I have already solved this problem. It is a question about PostgreSQL permission settings. Open pg_hba.conf in the installation directory and modify the md5 at the end of the document as trust as required. For example, if I use an administrator to log in to the IIS to run programs on an IPv6 network, modify the md5 of IPv6 local connections to trust.